# How many dollars does the US Senate bill keeping the gov't open till Feb 8, 2019 authroize?

Tags: united-states, senate

The senate passed a spending bill this week which would keep the government open to Feb 8, 2019.  How many dollars does that authorize to be spent?

*Extra credit for anyone who can link the official senate bill from their website.  I'm not being successful in finding it myself, so I'd like to see how it is published so that I can learn how to find future spending bills myself.*

Comment: The bill: https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/695
The linked CBO analysis: https://www.cbo.gov/system/files?file=2018-12/hr695HousePassed_0.pdf  (it is not an _official senate bill_, but a house-originated appropriations bill which the Senate voted on this week).

Comment: @user4556274 Ahh, so I did find it... am I insane in believing the bill title and summary describe something reasonably different?  I saw all of the DoD related content and nothing else.

Comment: @CortAmmon: I don't blame you, this one has a weird history (which is not uncommon). The House passed it in 2017 as a modification of the National Child Protection Act (which has nothing to do with appropriations). Then the Senate amended it in January to fund the DoD. The House agreed to that amendment (and made their own amendment), but Congress passed an omnibus bill instead (H.R. 1625). The Senate amended it a second time to turn it into a continuing resolution, but neglected to rename it. Finally, the House amended it to attach border wall funding. It is now before the Senate.